# Javascript FileSaver saves empty files after writing large number of files

Tags: javascript, file, google-chrome, filesystems

### Background

I'm working on an internal project that basically can generate a video on the client side, but since there are no JavaScript video encoders I'm aware of, I'm just exporting each frame individually. I need to avoid uploading to the server; this is all happening on the client side.

### Implementation

I'm using this [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) (more specifically, Chrome's webkit FileSystem API) to save a large number of PNGs generated by an HTML5 canvas. I set Chrome to automatically download to a specific folder, so when I hit 'Save' it just takes off and saves something like 20 images per second. This works perfectly for my purposes.

If I could use [JSZip](http://stuartk.com/jszip/) to compress all these frames into one file before offering it to the client to save, I would, but I haven't even tried because there's just no way the browser will have enough memory to generate ~8000 640x480 PNGs and then compress them.

### Problem

The problem is that after a certain number of images, every file downloaded is empty. Chrome even starts telling me in the download bar that the file is 0 bytes. Repeated on the same project with the same export settings, the empty saves start at exactly the same time. For example, with one project, I can save the first 5494 frames before it chokes. (I know this is an insanely large number, but I can't help that.) I tried setting a 10ms delay between saves, but that didn't have any effect. I haven't tried a larger delay because exporting takes a very long time as it is.

I checked the blob.size and it's never zero. I suspect it's exceeding some quota, but there are no errors thrown; it just silently fails to either write to the sandbox or copy the file to the user-specified location.

### Questions

How can I detect these empty saves? Prevent them? Is there a better way to do this? Am I just screwed?

---

EDIT: Actually, after debugging FileSaver.js, I realized that it's not even using webkitRequestFileSystem; it returns when it gets here:

```
if (can_use_save_link) {
    object_url = get_object_url(blob);
    save_link.href = object_url;
    save_link.download = name;
    if (click(save_link)) {
        filesaver.readyState = filesaver.DONE;
        dispatch_all();
        return;
    }
}
```

So, it looks like it's not even using the FileSystem API, and therefore I have no idea how to empty the storage before it's full.

---

EDIT 2: I tried moving the "if (can_use_save_link)" block to inside the "writer.onwriteend" function, and changing it to this:

```
if (can_use_save_link) {
    save_link.href = file.toURL();
    save_link.download = name;
    click(save_link);
}else{
    target_view.location.href = file.toURL();
}
```

The result is I'm able to save all 8260 files (about 1.5GB total) since it's now using storage with a quota. Before, the files didn't show up in the HTML5 FileSystem because I assume you didn't need to put them there if the anchor element supported the 'download' attribute.

I was also able to comment out the code that appends ".download" to the filename, and I had to provide an empty anonymous function as an argument to both instances of "file.remove()".

Comment: Just to make sure - how large are those 5494 files together? You're basically only allowed to use 10% of the hard disk space if you're requesting a temporary file system, which FileSaver.js [appears](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/blob/master/FileSaver.js#L145) to be using. ([See here for more information.](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/11/Quota-Management-API-Fast-Facts)).

Comment: Just checked, and they total 0.99GB. My hard drive capacity is about 450GB and has 339GB free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up modifying FileSaver.js (see "EDIT 2" in the original post).

Answer (score 0):

Use JSZip, it won't use too much memory if you disable compression (which is the default). To manually disable compression anyways, make sure to pass `compression: "STORE"` when calling `zip.generate()`.

Comment: This seems to be working so far, but I can't figure out how to use FileSaver to save out the generated .zip file. The method I'm using now is generating an invalid zip file. I'm trying to use a BlobBuilder like this:

    var bb = new BlobBuilder;
    bb.append(app.Analysis.playback.zip.generate());
    saveAs(bb.getBlob("application/zip"), app.Analysis.playback.baseFilename+'.zip');

Comment: Also, I'm generating the images from canvas using canvas.toDataURL('image/png'), so adding them to the zip file requires keeping all these base64-encoded PNGs in memory at once, right? Using this method, the browser tab crashes when it decides it's had enough. Do you know of a better way to do this?

Comment: Try out canvas.toBlob() instead: https://github.com/eligrey/canvas-toBlob.js - for browsers without BlobBuilder, you can also try out https://github.com/eligrey/BlobBuilder.js